# Authentication error Supabase and Prisma on Nextjs

Tags: next.js, prisma, supabase

This is the error message I’m getting when i run `npx prisma db push`

I’ve created a project, database and a table in Supabase

I also have the `schema.prisma` file and passing the `DATABASE_URL`  from Supabase in my project directory

This is the error message I’m getting

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "db.klxgywdlqfhjavtw.supabase.co:6413"

Error: Migration engine error:
db error: FATAL: SASL authentication failed
```

I’ve tried a few things:

Checking the `DATABASE_URL`  is correct from the Supabase project
Deleted and Created again a project in Supabase
Created a new Schema in the `schema.prisma` file
I tried running the Supabase Cli but then there’s some Docker issues to get past first…

I’ve tried a few things:

Checking the `DATABASE_URL`  is correct from the Supabase project
Deleted and Created again a project in Supabase
Created a new Schema in the `schema.prisma` file
I tried running the Supabase Cli but then there’s some Docker issues to get past first…

Comment: Did you manage to fix this in the end? we have a guide here for Prisma use with Supabase https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma

Comment: Are you using latest version of Prisma?

Comment: Same issue here. I get "Authentication error" even when I try to connect direction with PSQL. It's intermittent. Sometimes I can get in, but most of the time it fails with that error.